# Get the Image Path from Json and assign to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Before I put the Image path in variable as below :

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 var output = "http://sitename.com/images/oneheart.png";
 //some other code
});
```

Now I need to get the **Image path** from Json file , so i tried as below :

Both Json & html file are in same path....

**Json** :

```
{
  "path" : " shape\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : ""   
  },
  "name" : "shape",
  "layers" : [
    {     
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {         
          "name" : "bg_rectangle_1"
        },
        {         
          "height" : 475,
          "layers" : [
            {

              "src" : "http://sitename.com/images/oneheart.png",             
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {              
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],          
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        }
      ],      
      "name" : "loveshape_17"
    }
  ]
}
```

**script** :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON('oneheart.json', function(data) // Get data from JSON file
        {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < json.layers.length; i++) {
                var output += json.layers[i].src; // Place image in variable 
            }
        });
    // Some other code
});
```

Here is [Full Json file in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pChkBaHV) & Full code in [codepen](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/WPqoNj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as below, it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var output= "";
var mask1;
//Shubham Chaudhary code

$.getJSON('./oneheart.json', function(json){
  for(let layer of json.layers){
    if(layer.layers && layer.layers.length > 0){
      for(let temp of layer.layers){
        if(temp.src) output = temp.src;
        else if (temp.layers){
          for(let tl of temp.layers)
             if(tl.src) output = tl.src;
        }
      }
    }
  }

      mask1 = $(".container").mask({
        maskImageUrl: output,
        onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
            img.css({
                "position": "fixed",
                "left": 73,
                "top": 1
          });
        }
    });
});
}); // end of document ready
```

Comment: Thanks, Well, mask images are fetching from json file now, but `when user upload image, its not uploading`, here is console errors : http://prnt.sc/mome15

Comment: move `var mask1` outside document.ready. or move input.onchange inside document.ready

Comment: moved `var mask1` outside `document.ready` , but no luck.... here is code :   https://pastebin.com/7cYiVaUZ

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine.... in some json files in `"src"` only image name is present as `"src" : "oneheart.png" instead of `http: //sitename.com/images/oneheart.png` in that case please tell me how to get the image ?

Comment: if you have the src = `oneheart.png` translate it to `/images/oneheart.png` or `images/oneheart.png` and the canvas Image will take care of the rest , it will be translated to `http://sitename.com/images/oneheart.png`

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually parse the JSON file and get the image url. Do something like this

```
$.getJSON('./oneheart.json', function(json){
  //var json = $.parse(data);
  var imageUrl = "";
  for(let layer of json.layers){
    if(layer.layers && layer.layers.length > 0){
      for(let temp of layer.layers){
        if(temp.src) imageUrl = temp.src;
      }
    }
  }

  var output="";
  if(imageUrl){
    console.log(imageUrl);
    output=imageUrl;
  }

});
```

And this is async operation, you need to put other code in a function and call it inside this callback

Comment: Thanks , i updated your code in my file  : https://pastebin.com/tAG4tkt8 , i got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` in console....

Comment: Edited. It should now console.log the imageUrl from the file. You need to use this imageUrl to load it.

Comment: i updated your code in [link](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/s.html) , i got console errors , please check  : http://prnt.sc/mojqgq

Comment: Can you try now

Comment: can you please refresh the link, some errors are reduced , but still some are there as http://prnt.sc/mojwyf ....

Comment: Edited. Also, you need to call all your other inside this callback function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188875/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-shubham-chaudhary).

Answer (score 0):

Your output variable is declared only in your json file handler. At the place of `// some other code` it is not available any more. Since i guess the json loading will happen asynchronously it is not sufficent to just move the variable declaration outside of the json file handler. You can either do everything inside of the json file handler. Or you use the promise like [jqXHR Api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Also it looks like you want all srcs as individual values in an array and not a concatenated string. So you want to [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over all layers.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('oneheart.json')
    .done(parseData)
    .done(doSthWithOutput)
    .fail(handleError);
}

function parseData(data){
  if (!data){throw "missing data"};
  var json = $.parseJSON(data);
  return json.layers.map(function(layer){return layer.src;});
}

function doSthWithOutput(output){
  // Some more code
}

function handleError(err) {
  // do something in case of error
}
```